# R ggplot label number of observations per ordered violin with facet wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got a plot that looks like the output of the following code using the iris data

```
require(tidyverse)
require(purrr)
require(forcats) # Useful for ordering facets found at [here][1]

# Make some long data and set a custom sorting order using some of t
tbl <- iris %>% 
       pivot_longer(., cols = 1:4, names_to = "Msr", values_to = "Vls") %>%
       mutate(Msr = factor(Msr)) %>% 
       mutate(plot_fct = fct_cross(Species, Msr)) %>%                              
       mutate(plot_fct = fct_reorder(plot_fct, Vls))                           


# A functioning factory for minor log breaks found [here][1] (very helpful)
minor_breaks_log <- function(base) {
  # Prevents lazy evaluation
  force(base) 
  # Wrap calculation in a function that the outer function returns
  function(limits) {
    ggplot2:::calc_logticks(
      base = base, 
      minpow = floor(log(limits[1], base = base)), 
      maxpow = ceiling(log(limits[2], base = base))
    )$value
  }
}


# Plot the images
ggplot(data = tbl, aes(x =plot_fct, y = Vls, fill = Species)) +
       geom_violin() +
       coord_flip() +                                                               # swap coords
       scale_y_log10(labels = function(x) sprintf("%g", x),
                     minor_breaks = minor_breaks_log(10)) +                       # format for labels                                           # box fills
       theme_bw(base_size = 12) +
       annotation_logticks(base = 10, sides = "b") +
       facet_wrap(~Species, nrow = 1, scales = "free")
```

[image: Violin plots]

I would now like to list the number of observations per violin on the right side of each facet just inside the maximum border, which I'm sure is possible but cannot seem to find an example that does this sort of labeling, with violins and facets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ggplot(data = tbl, aes(y = plot_fct, fill = Species)) +
  geom_violin(aes(x = Vls)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = after_stat(count)), hjust = 1,
            stat = "count", position = "fill") +
  scale_x_log10(labels = function(x) sprintf("%g", x),
                minor_breaks = minor_breaks_log(10)) +                       # format for labels                                           # box fills
  theme_bw(base_size = 12) +
  annotation_logticks(base = 10, sides = "b") +
  facet_wrap(~Species, nrow = 1, scales = "free")
```

[image]